# using a dynamic dns as a name server

Tags: domain-name-system, dynamic-dns

I'm playing with hosting my own website on a residential internet connection. I have a dynamic ip assigned but the isp also gives me a dynamic dns domain name, something like xxx.go.ro . I bought a domain name from a registrar and i want to host my own dns server and configure the nameserver of the bought domain to the dynamic dns address given by my isp so the xxx.go.ro will become the ns for my domain. My question is: is it a good idea to have the ip of the domain name server dynamically change? I don't understand if the tld caches the ip address of the nameserver. Should i use an external service for dns like luands and just point cnames to my subdomains? I would really like to host my own dns to experiment with it.

Answer (score 1):

Bought from a registrar? You need a nameserver with static IP. Even two nameservers with static IPs. You need them to appear in glue records of parent zone; I doubt TLD zones support updating records often enoung, and that they permit setting TTL short enough. TLD DNS zones are *really huge* and it is likely very hard to update them often.
Also, you likely need to do updates programmatically via some API, rather than usual human-oriented web interface of your registrar. Do they have any?

For the 3rd level subdomain, it is pretty possible. I developed a dynamic DNS service 10 years ago. Something like DynDNS, but I implemented a possibility to have a subdomain delegation with NS pointing to a dynamically-updated glue record. After 10 years passed, *no one* was found to be using this feature.

There is a caveat, a service itself is hosted on usual static nameservers, and only allows dynamic updates of its hosted domains (just one domain, currently). So if I say it hosts dynamic DNS of `example.com`, it is possible to delegate `sub.example.com` to some nameserver with dynamic IP address. You can easily implement such service yourself and "for yourself" with your owned domain name, but it's core nameservers still must live with static addresses; the best you can do this way is to have subdomain of your domain to be delegated to dynamic address.

Answer (score 0):

You need a static IP if you want to host your own DNS server.  But why do you want to host your own DNS server?  What's the need?  Just let you host do it and you configure DNS records as needed.  Plus, you should have a GREAT understanding of DNS before trying to tackle hosting your own DNS server.  Mistakes with TTL, IP addresses, etc. can leave you in a world of hurt.  And that's before getting into security...

Comment: And we don't support _anything_ at home anyway.

Comment: Well, my goal is to have automatic website deploys with my own infrastructure. That means from code commit to live website without any intervention, that means also automatically configuring the nameserver.

> You need a static IP if you want to host your own DNS server
Why is that? is it a caching issue? Is it something else?

Comment: You can do that without hosting your own DNS server though.  Automated code deployment and authoritative DNS servers are not synonymous.  AT ALL.  I can't tell what you are trying to accomplish at this point.  But you need a static IP, because you need to set an NS record to something for your domain.  I mean, it doesn't have to be a static IP, but you'll have to update it, and you'll have to then contend with TTL after it is updated.  Just trust me when I say if you don't know the answers to the basic DNS questions, you aren't ready to host a DNS server.  Just have your host do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a service like https://www.dnsexit.com/  point to you domain that.
On there can setup Dynamic to web site at your house.
There is software to install to keep IP updated